# How do I add all my servers to each others /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts

Tags: ansible

I need to make sure, that all my servers per default trust each other, so I don't have to be prompted to trust the hosts when I setup ssh tunnels between my servers. How can I do that with ansible?

All my servers are stop with host names which can be accessed via: `"{{ groups['all'] }}"`

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple of options here.

You can ignore known_hosts entirely by adding

```
StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

To each servers' `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`.

Or you could use [`ssh-keyscan`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ssh-keyscan&sektion=1) to add all of the hosts to each servers' known hosts with the equivalent of:

```sh
ssh-keyscan -H {host_name} >> path/to/known_hosts
```

This might look something like:

```
name: Add all hosts in inventory to known_hosts
shell: ssh-keyscan -H {{ item }} >> path/to/known_hosts
with_items: "{{ groups['all'] }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Here in my answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72770110/1333025) to *"How to include all host keys from all hosts in group"* I created a small Ansible [look-up module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html#lookup-plugins) `host_ssh_keys` to extract public SSH keys from the host inventory, which I believe addresses your use-case.

Adding all hosts' public ssh keys to  `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts` is then as simple as this, thanks to Ansible's integration of [loops with look-up plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html#using-lookup-plugins):

```yaml
- name: Add public keys of inventory hosts to known_hosts
  ansible.builtin.known_hosts:
    path: /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
    name: "{{ item.host }}"
    key: "{{ item.known_hosts }}"
  with_host_ssh_keys: "{{ groups['mygroup'] }}"
```